# Rebuilt index remains fragmented

Tags: sql-server

When the rebuild  script has run I still have a fair share of index fragmented. It is very hard to find any information on this.

I have done a lot of testing and I think I have two issues. 
Rebuild does not work well on tables heavily used in DDL/DML operations. It works 90% better on a disconnected database.
Can this be addressed without a service window?

I think the remaining 10% is due to fragmentation on disk level.
Should I separate the SQL application logs (error logs etc) from the data files? I can't find any info on this due to the 10 000 hits on trans logs. 
My provider puts the data files on the main instance disk (separate from tempdb, trans & OS)

Comment: off-topic - belongs on [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

be as it it may with disk level fragmentation, it can't be addressed on a SSD SAN.

The best solution I can find is to only include index_level=0. This is what Hallengren's script does and I guess that is good enough for me then.

```
        SELECT
            CASE WHEN MAX(ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent) > 30 THEN
                'ALTER INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON [' + sc.NAME + '].[' + so.NAME + '] REBUILD  With (maxdop = 1);'
            ELSE
                'ALTER INDEX [' + i.name + '] ON [' + sc.NAME + '].[' + so.NAME + '] REORGANIZE ;'
            END AS [query], max( ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent)
        FROM
            sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats (DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL, 'DETAILED') AS ps
            INNER JOIN sys.indexes i
                ON ps.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID
                    AND ps.index_id = i.index_id
                    AND ps.database_id = DB_ID()
                    AND i.name is not NULL
                    AND ps.avg_fragmentation_in_percent > 5 -- min % to return
                    AND ps.page_count > 1000 -- otherwise table is to smal.
                    AND ps.index_level = 0
            INNER JOIN sys.objects so
                ON i.OBJECT_ID = so.OBJECT_ID
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas sc
                ON sc.SCHEMA_ID = so.SCHEMA_ID
        GROUP BY sc.NAME, so.NAME, ps.index_id, i.name
        ORDER BY sc.NAME, so.NAME, ps.index_id DESC;
```